# Styled Components - How to style a component passed as a prop?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to build this simple component which takes title and Icon Component as props and renders them. The icons I use here are third party components like the ones from Material UI.

**option.component.jsx**

```
import { Wrapper } from './option.styles';

function Option({ title, Icon }) {
   return (
      <Wrapper>
         {Icon && <Icon />}
         <h4>{title}</h4>
      </Wrapper>
   );
}
```

**option.styles.js**

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Wrapper = styled.div`
   display: flex;
   color: grey;

   &:hover {
      color: white;
   }
`;

// export const Icon =
```

I've organized all my styles in a separate file and I intend to keep it that way.
I want to style `<Icon />` , but I don't want to do it inside Option Component like this.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Wrapper } from './option.styles';

function Option({ title, Icon }) {
   const IconStyled = styled(Icon)`
      margin-right: 10px;
   `;

   return (
      <Wrapper>
         {Icon && <IconStyled />}
         <h4>{title}</h4>
      </Wrapper>
   );
}
```

What is the best way to style a component passed as a prop while maintaining this file organization?
I've looked through the documentation and I wasn't able find anything related to this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can pass a styled icon from outside where you are using `Option` Component. The `Icon` is just a prop name, you can pass any component by using `Icon={StyledIcon}`.

Comment: How `Icon` component is defined?  I mean, how do you pass an icon to the option? can you add an example of icon?

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto The icons I'm using here are the ones from Material UI.

I pass them to Option as 
<Option title="home" Icon={HomeIcon} />.

HomeIcon is imported from Material UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in 2 ways:

**1. As a SVG Icon ([svg-icon](https://material-ui.com/api/svg-icon/)):**

***option.styles.js*** as:

```js
import styled from "styled-components";
import SvgIcon from "@material-ui/core/SvgIcon";


export const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  color: grey;

  &:hover {
    color: black;
  }
`;

export const IconStyled = styled(SvgIcon)`
  margin-right: 10px;
`;
```

And in your component, do like that:

```js
import { Wrapper, IconStyled } from "./option.styles";

function Option({ title, Icon }) {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {Icon && <IconStyled component={Icon} />}
      <h4>{title}</h4>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Option title="title" Icon={HomeIcon}></Option>
      <Option title="title" Icon={AccessAlarmIcon}></Option>
    </>
  );
};
```

**2. As a Font Icon ([font-icons](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#icon-font-icons)):**

Import material icons in `<head>`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
```

***option.styles.js*** as:

```js
import styled from "styled-components";
import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon";

export const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  color: grey;

  &:hover {
    color: black;
  }
`;

export const IconStyled = styled(Icon)`
  margin-right: 10px;
`;
```

And in your component, do like that:

```js
import { Wrapper, IconStyled } from "./option.styles";

function Option({ title, icon }) {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {icon && <IconStyled>{icon}</IconStyled>}
      <h4>{title}</h4>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Option title="title" icon='star'></Option>
      <Option title="title" icon='home'></Option>
    </>
  );
};
```